# Computer Complexity of a real case scenario: facility location

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

There is a problem of facility location that I solve with genetic algorithms.

I can get good results. So I would like to compare my genetic algorithm complexity O(n^2) with the brute-force algorithm. But I am not getting an answer.

```
(n = number of individuals in my population, usually 200.)
```

See the picture attached. Ignore the gray and pink squares.
I want to know the complexity to find all the solutions for the problem.
The problem is how I can connect the blue circle to the black squares.

In the picture, you can see one possible combination.

But in the worse scenario I see a O(k!), where k is the number of available places (20x20 in this case = 400).

If that is correct, in the worst scenario this would take 400! to be computed.

How I did it? I considered that for the first k places in the scenario I would have k-1 available places, and so on. In the worst case, I would have:

```
k.(k-1).(k-2).(k-3),...,1 possibilities
```

Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what the restrictions are for your problem.

Can I connect all the black squares directly to blue dots? If I can, then why would I consider all of the 400 squares?

Comment: Yes you can.  But a brute-force algorithm must consider all the possibilities, right? Because of this I am considering all the 400 squares. I am trying to compare my algorithm (Genetic) or any other to a brute-force one... just to show the difference of complexity between them. (I do not know if I make myself clear, if not, please let me know) Thanks Chris

Comment: By the looks of it you need to go to any square first, and then the black square? If you can go right to the black square then there is no problem - just draw a line from each black square to the closest blue dot. 

The problem definition still needs a better description I think. What value are we trying to optimize ? GAs are optimization heuristics ... so what is the measurement of the cost of connecting the squares and blue circles

Comment: If you make only one stop at a coordinate before going to the blue dot, then the algorithm would be 400 * blue_dots for each black square.
If you can make any number of stops, then its 400! * blue_dots * black_squares. But I don't see why you would do this, when there's no value in computing all possible paths

Comment: Thanks for your help Cris... Yes I can go from one blue dot straight to the black square. This would be the shortest way. But if I have obstacles in the path (like the pink square)... them I am not able to take the straight line anymore. So I may have others alternatives. I can create anything different and better than a brute-froce algorithm. We can create a heuristic for it even. But in the end, I would ask you if the program that you made is faster than the brute-force algorithm. (that happened to me)

Comment: So I would say: brute-force is not smart and take O(n!), but my program takes O(n^2). I am quite sure the brute-force is not a good option... but is not an option to the Salesman Traveller Problem too... and we still compare heuritics algorithms to the complexity O(n!) of the STP. See my point?

Comment: In a different forum someone told me that:
https://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_arrangements

And I think it is right... what do you say?


(The second blue square you can ignore, please.)

Comment: Yes, if we need to go around the pink squares then the brute force algorithm would be O(n!) in the worst case